# Let $G$ be a finite group such that if $A, B\le G$ then $AB\le G$. Prove $G$ is a solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group satisfying the following property: (*) If $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$ then $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$. Prove $G$ is solvable.

So I felt like a good place to start is to let $|G| = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a^2}...p_r^{a_r}$ such that each $p_i$ is a distinct prime, and then Let for each $i = 1, 2, ..., r$ Let $H_i$ be a Sylow$_{p_i}$ subgroup. So $G = H_1H_2..H_r$ and each $H_i$ is solvable since all $p$-groups are solvable.

I was then thinking that a good idea since I know by Burnside's Theorem that $H_iH_j$ is solvable, to try and use induction and prove that if $H_1H_2...H_m$ is solvable then $H_1H_2...H_mH_{m+ 1}$ is sovable, but I can't figure it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you let $A$ and $B$ be two different Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$? (Since you want to use Sylow's theorem to solve this, this is one way to do it. There are many.)

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are two different Sylow $P$ subgroups then $AB$ must be a $p$-group but since $B \leq AB \leq G$ and $B$ is maximal among $p$-groups in $G$, it follows that $B = AB$, hence there dose not exist $2$ different Sylow$_p$ groups for any prime $p$.  So since all Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal $G$ is nilpotent and hence solvable.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, most nilpotent groups do not have this property either, but that isn't important for your question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give another proof, but proving $G$ is soluble only, using Burnside's result. It might be what weas meant by the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another proof, now that you have the answer. Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of coprime order. Then $\langle x\rangle\langle y\rangle$ is a subgroup, and has order $o(x)\cdot o(y)$. Thus any two elements of coprime order commute.

It turns out this is enough to prove the result: a finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if every $2$-generated subgroup is nilpotent.

But let's not use that, and let $z$ be an element in the centre of some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Consider $C_G(z)$. It contains all elements of order prime to $p$, and also contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, thus is all of $G$. Thus $z\in Z(G)\neq 1$.

Since your condition is inherited by quotients, we see that $G$ must possess a central series, hence is nilpotent.

---

Edit: some more on the structure of these groups. In general (i.e., infinite groups), they are locally nilpotent. The finite ones were mostly classified by Iwasawa in 1941, but there were some gaps that were filled by Napolitani and Janko.

A $p$-group is quasihamiltonian (i.e., $AB$ is a subgroup for all $A,B\leq G$) if and only if

1. It has an abelian normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is cyclic, and there exists a generator $x$ of $G/N$, and an integer $n$, such that $a^x=a^{1+p^n}$ for all $a\in A$, or
2. $p=2$, and $G$ is the direct product of $Q_8$ and an elementary abelian $2$-group.

A subgroup $H$ such that $HK=KH$ (i.e., $HK$ is a subgroup) for all $K\leq G$ is called a *permutable* subgroup. The above groups are those where all subgroups are permutable. There's been recent research on groups where lots of, but not all, subgroups are permutable.

---

Edit 2: here's another proof, which given you mention Burnside's $p^\alpha q^\beta$ theorem, might have been the intention of your tutor (assuming you are doing a course).

Let $x\in G$ have order $p$ for some $p\mid |G|$. By the above method, we see that $y\in C_G(x)$ for all elements $y\in G$ of order prime to $p$. But now this means that $|G:C_G(x)|$ is a power of $p$. By that useful theorem you did while proving Burnside's $p^\alpha q^\beta$ theorem, $G$ cannot be a non-abelian simple group. Thus $G$ possesses a normal subgroup $N$. The condition is inherited by both $N$ and $G/N$, so by induction both of these are soluble. Thus $G$ is soluble.

Comment: Nice!  Do you know of a nonabelian nilpotent group with the required property?  Of course, it is sufficient to look at $p$-groups.

Comment: The quaternion group $Q_8$ is one.

Comment: Thanks for the additional remark and the example.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete that remark. That classified all so-called M-groups, which are groups such that the lattice of subgroups is modular. These strictly include the groups we are talking about here.

Comment: I see.  I was searching for quasihamiltonian groups for a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: As it happens, modular lattice groups and quasihamiltonian groups coincide for $p$-groups, so my original list is correct! I will edit my answer to include this information. Checking it more thoroughly, Iwasawa's proof has some gaps, that we filled by Napolitani and Janko.

Answer (score 4):

**Claim**: All Sylow subgroups of $G$ are normal.

*Proof*: Suppose $P_1,P_2$ are different Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.  Then the group $P_1P_2$ is a $p$-group that is strictly larger than $P_1$, contradiction.

**Corollary**: $G$ is solvable.

Comment: See also: my comment on the question.

Comment: Why exactly $P_1P_2$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: @QuangHoang If $A,B$ are subgroups of a group $G$, the number of elements of the elementwise product $AB$ is $\frac{\lvert A\rvert\cdot\lvert B\rvert}{\lvert A\cap B\rvert}$.  Apply this to $A=P_1$, $B=P_2$.